# How to select rows only from the newest timestamp, when table is partitioned by timestamp column?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a **very big table** in a database of **Oracle**.

The table has a **timestamp column** which is the **parition key** of the table, which means that it's the fastest to filter on this column when looking for results in the last x days (for example).
something like:

`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE time > sysdate - 1`

Now, what I am looking for is the only rows that have been inserted with the most updated timestamp column (the newest). And it's important to say that it could be more than 1 row so limit by row numbers might not work.

What I did and it worked was:

```
SELECT product, time
from some_table
where time in (
SELECT max(time) from some_table
)
```

And it worked, but from my knowledge(and correct me if I am wrong) it's very not efficient (and still takes time on big tables), because the db still goes through all the rows to find the maximum timestamp, and then in the outer SELECT it's going again on all the rows to find only those who match.

Because this table is ordered by the timestamp,
**I wish to make an efficient query where it stops to search when it meets an older timestmap from the newest one, which is also the first one he saw.**

For example:

```
Product, time
Blowdry, 2020-05-22 09:00:30
Book,    2020-05-22 09:00:30
Phone,   2020-05-22 09:00:30
PC,      2020-05-22 08:30:15 -- Here I want the db to stop and show only the 3 rows above
... (Many rows)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine.  However, you should use `=` rather than `in`:

```
select product, time
from some_table
where time = (select max(t2.time) from some_table t2);
```

In fact, this can be quite fast with an index on `time`.  The subquery will use the index to get the maximum time.  The outer query will then use the index to fetch the rows that match.

In Oracle 12C, you can also use:

```
select product, time
from some_table
order by time desc
fetch first 1 row only with ties;
```

This should also use an index on `time`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what happens behind the last row in the db algorithm?